# Help Text for WFFM Form Designer

Tags: wffm

I think it would be really useful for Content Authors if when we create custom fields we could add help text for the fields properties like you do for Fields on an Items Data Template in Sitecore. This would allow you to explain things about the options in smaller light-grey text under or next to the field property.

I've mocked up how this might look below using an example of a custom date field we use.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve?

Comment: I'm guessing I'd need to inherit every single field type where I'd like to do this and override the rendering method to handle this which would suck.